# CakePHP 3 Query Builder - How to use max function with a condition?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, query-builder

How can I use max function with a condition?

It's like the following answer in [Translate SQL query to CakePHP 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32527846/translate-sql-query-to-cakephp-3-0), but in my case I need to use the max function and the case clause (or any other form of condition):

```
$options['contain'] = array('Users');
$query = $this->Pictures->find('all', $options);
$query->select(['Users.username', 'Users.plan', 'Users.id']);
$query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('size'),])
      ->select(['count' => $query->func()->count('*'),])
      ->select(['facebook' => $query->func()
          ->count('case when type = \'facebook\' then 1 else null end'),])
      ->select(['instagram' => $query->func()
          ->count('case when type = \'instagram\' then 1 else null end'),])
      ->select(['device' => $query->func()
           ->count('case when type = \'device\' then 1 else null end'),])
      ->group('user_id');

return $query;
```

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 2):

```
$query->select(['max_size' => $query->func()->max('size')])
```

Using SQL Functions-
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions